# run cron job command in php file with parameters

Tags: php, cron

I did code in PHP file to generate output in some using cron job after every 5 minutes. Right now, output file is generated but the issue is it doesn't taking parameters as described in cron job command.

```
**test.php**
<?php
       system('*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/admin/public_html/domain.com/public/cron/task.php "id=1" >> /home/admin/public_html/domain.com/list/task.txt 2>&1
  ');
   ?>

**task.php**
<?php
       $arr = $_SERVER['argv'];
       print_r($arr);
?>
```

Now if I set cron job in ssh or cpanel of test.php without parameters

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/admin/public_html/domain.com/public/cron/task.php >> /home/admin/public_html/domain.com/list/task.txt 2>&1
```

It will generate task.txt file but not get those parameters which I pass in **system** function.

But if I set cron job with parameters in ssh

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/admin/public_html/domain.com/public/cron/task.php "id=1" >> /home/admin/public_html/domain.com/list/task.txt 2>&1
```

It will get those parameters and output correct results.
So, my question is how could i perform an operation to run cron job in php with parameters not manually in ssh or cpanel.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `exec` command ?

Comment: @HardikPatel yeah I tried.